# How to align top-bar items with row

Tags: html, css

I have a `header.top-bar` element at the top (with `div.top-bar-left` and `div.top-bar-right` elements inside), then everything after that is inside a `div.row` element. What's the simplest way to make the items in the top bar line up with the edges of the row? I tried putting the header itself inside a row but that just completely messed up the placement of everything.

[image]

Comment: place top-bar-left & top-bar-right html in <div class="container">  </div>

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
 // place your html code here
</div>
```

> Check this!

```
<!-- Navigation Start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

  <!-- Container Start -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Note that the .navbar-collapse and .collapse classes have been removed from the #navbar -->
    <div id="navbar">

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

  </div>
  <!-- Container End -->
</nav>
<!-- Navigation End-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the row and top-bar in a div and use flex-property

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-bar">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```